# Setting action for links in a class usinv data-attributes and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I want to set links to perform a few different actions on click, all depending on one single attribute. My idea is to do something like

`<a class='biglink' data-attrib='attr'></a>`

And have a link appear automatically with the actions performed. I tried adding javascript at the end as

```js
<script>
    $('.biglink').each(function(){
    var tar = '#' + $(this).data('attrib');
    $(this).setAttribute('href',tar);
    $(this).innerHTML = 'Link to ' + $(this).data('attrib');
    });
</script>
```

but it does not seem to do anything. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) are vanilla JavaScript's method and attribute. Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) when using jQuery:

```js
$('.biglink').each(function(){
  var tar = '#' + $(this).data('attrib');
  $(this).attr('href', tar);
  $(this).html('Link to ' + $(this).data('attrib'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='biglink' data-attrib='attr'></a>
```